# Can't use my GPU (AMD/WIN10)

Tags: gpu

Ryzen 5 3600, RX590, 16gb RAM, chipset & graphics driver up to date as is Windows.
I've uninstalled & reinstalled blender but still nothing.
Here's the debug.

```
I0611 04:36:52.234308 16820 device.cpp:47] CUEW initialization failed: Error opening the library 
I0611 04:36:52.249321 16820 device.cpp:32] HIPEW initialization succeeded 
I0611 04:36:52.249321 16820 device.cpp:34] Found precompiled kernels 
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator. 
Blender 3.5.1 
Build: 2023-04-24 23:56:35 Windows release 
argv[0] = D:\\blender 
argv[1] = --debug 
argv[2] = --debug-cycles 
argv[3] = --python-expr 
argv[4] = import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.sysinfo(filepath=r'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\blender\debug_logs\blender_system_info.txt')
Read prefs: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.5\config\userpref.blend 
Registering file extension...success (user) 
Info: File association registered
 
Saved session recovery to 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\quit.blend'
Writing userprefs: 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Blender
Foundation\Blender\3.5\config\userpref.blend' ok 
Info: Preferences saved
```

Comment: This site cannot help with Blender crashes or technical problems running Blender. There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here have any association with the Blender Foundation so your question is off-topic here. See "What not to ask" [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Report your issue via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu.

Comment: It's probably because of the "CUEW initialization failed: Error opening the library" error. I have no idea what this exactly means. Blender 3.0 no longer supports OpenCL, it uses now HIP and hardware ray-tracing is not fully supported yet. Maybe your GPU is too old. Have yo tried Blender 2.9 LTS?